# Amazon AWS EFS - automount from fstab not working at boot, but runs fine live

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-efs, mount-point, fstab

I am looking to connect shared EFS mount points to our EC2 development instances. I wrote the mount points in `/etc/fstab`, and it runs fine when I test it with `sudo mount -fav`. However, it simply does not mount on reboot.

The thing that jumps out at me is that perhaps it's not detecting the AWS credentials correctly on boot since it's running as root and hasn't set up the environment yet? Here are the relevant lines, slightly anonymized. I have 2 access points (which will eventually be the real mounts), and I added in the whole EFS drive just to try a simpler case.

```
fs-********:/ /whole efs defaults,_netdev,noresvport,tls 0 0
fs-******** /dao efs defaults,_netdev,noresvport,tls,accesspoint=fsap-**************** 0 0
fs-********/dao/staging efs defaults,_netdev,noresvport,tls,accesspoint=fsap-**************** 0 0
```

Any thoughts?